# Typescript type definition for multidimensional nested arrays

Tags: typescript

How to define typescript type multidimensional matrix nested array The length of each array element in each layer is still the same?

```
type FixedArray<T, D extends number> = T[] & {
   length: D
}

type NestedArray<T> = T[] | NestedArray<T>[];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you'll have to nest the type `FixedArray`. You can do something like this -

```
type FixedLengthArray<Length extends number, Type = unknown> = Type[] & { length: Length };

type MultDimArray<NumRows extends number, NumCols extends number, Type = unknown> = FixedLengthArray<NumRows, FixedLengthArray<NumCols, Type>>

let a: MultDimArray<2, 3, string> = [['a', 'd', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'c']]
```

Comment: My description may not be accurate. The dimensions of nested arrays are unknown, and the length of each element present in each dimension is consistent when it is an array.

Comment: [
   // Dimension 1
   [ 

     // Dimension 2
     [1, 2], [2, 3] 
   ],
   [ 

     // Dimension 2
     [1, 2], [2, 3] 
   ],
   [ 

     // Dimension 2
     [1, 2], [2, 3] 
   ]
]

Comment: @NovaAstra could you update your question then to explain in an explicit manner, what you're looking for? It'd also be helpful if you include a typescript playground link that I can use for reference.